# Express the vectors $\vec{AC}, \vec{AD}, \vec{BE} , \vec{AE}, \vec{BF} ~~ \text{and} ~~ \vec{DF}$ as linear combination of $u$ and $v$

Tags: vectors

> > Consider the regular hexagon $ABCDEF$. Let $u=\vec{AB}$ and $v=\vec{BC}$.
>
> (a) Express the vectors $\vec{AC}, \vec{AD}, \vec{BE} , \vec{AE}, \vec{BF} ~~ \text{and} ~~ \vec{DF}$ as linear combination of $u$ and $v$.
>
> (b) Let $G$ be the midpoint of $EF$, and let $S$ be the intersection of $GB$ and $AC$. In what ratio does the $S$ divide the line segment $AC$.

I started off this problem using arbritary constants for coordinates of $ABCDEF$ respectively but using these coordinates give me a very ugly answer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you familiar with complex numbers? You could represent your hexagon using $6^{th}$ roots of unity.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You don't have to use coordinates.

(a) Note that $\overrightarrow{ED}=\overrightarrow{AB}=u$, $\overrightarrow{FE}=\overrightarrow{BC}=v$ and $\overrightarrow{AD}=2\overrightarrow{BC}=2v$.

$$\overrightarrow{CD}=\overrightarrow{AD}-\overrightarrow{AB}-\overrightarrow{BC}=\overrightarrow{BC}-\overrightarrow{AB}=v-u$$

So $\overrightarrow{AC}=\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BC}=u+v$, $\overrightarrow{BE}=2\overrightarrow{CD}=2v-2u$,

$$\overrightarrow{AE}=\overrightarrow{BD}=\overrightarrow{BC}+\overrightarrow{CD}=v+v-u=2v=u$$

$\overrightarrow{BF}$ and $\overrightarrow{DF}$ can be found by similar method.

(b) Find $\overrightarrow{BG}$ and let $\overrightarrow{BS}=k\overrightarrow{BG}$. Then $\overrightarrow{AS}=\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BS}$ is parallel to $\overrightarrow{AC}$

Comment: How do I find the linear combination tho?

Comment: Part (a) or (b)?

Comment: The linear combination to part (a)

Comment: just use vector addition law repeatedly.